# Moving Data From One Workbook To Another With Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a new workbook with data from an already existing workbook. The existing workbook is extremely large so I have it loaded as a read-only workbook.
Because of this, I need to iterate through the rows but I can't seem to figure out how to do this AND get data into the new workbook. 
Along with this, the data is from column A and is only put into the new workbook if the cell in column B say "IL".

```
for row in existing_sheet.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=2):
    for cell in row:
        print("CHECKING IF IT IS IN IL")
        if "IL" in str(cell.value):
            currSheet.cell(row=counter, column=1).value = existing_sheet.cell(row=counter, column=41).value
```

I keep getting deprecation warnings and the program is going much slower than I think it should be.
When I simply do a print statement to see the cell value, it goes through all 40,000 rows in just a few minutes. 
My current code takes hours, if not longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`existing_sheet.cell(row=counter, column=41).value`
This is what is slowing everything down. In read-only mode every call to `iter_rows()` or `cell()` will force openpyxl to parse the worksheet again. But you will need to have a wider row to get the 41st cell `row[40]`.

```
for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=41):
    if "IL" in row[2].value:
        ws2.cell(row=row[2].row, column=1).value = row[40].value
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for your help Charlie! Just one question: what exactly would be the difference in doing `row=row[2].row` as opposed to using a counter?

Comment: As the row information is available from every cell there is no need for a counter, so less to go wrong.